# What material is used to make the interior sidewalls panels, ceiling as well as luggage bins in a commercial aircraft?

Tags: cabin-design, aerospace-materials

What material is use to make the interior sidewalls panels, ceiling as well as luggage bins? All these elements seems to be made of similar material.

What is the weight these cabin interior elements represent for a typical single aisle aircraft like the A320?

Comment: I presume Polycarbonat or even more likely Fibre-reinforced plastic? I miss Polycarbonat on modern smartphones, better feeling in the hands and doesn‘t break like glass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The materials used in aircraft are similar regardless of airline or type of aircraft, since all passenger-carrying craft must meet  flammability requirements.

The side panels, the ceiling and the luggage bins are made out of a Glass Fiber Reinforced Plastic (**GFRP**) that must meet fire/smoke/toxicity (FST) requirements.The small window shade panels that slide down to cover airline windows, are typically thermoformed polyetherketoneketone (**PEKK**) plastic sheet. Some other high performance thermoplastics can be found on an airliner's interior, like the polyetheretherketone (**PEEK**) and the polyvinyl fluoride (**PVF**) (mostly as decorative surfaces laminate).

Reference: https://www.compositesworld.com/articles/advanced-materials-for-aircraft-interiors

Comment: I'm not doubting you, however some references would turn a nice answer into a really good one.